Ebay Scraping to avoid listings that include "results matching fewer words"
I am trying to scrape eBay sold listings for products I have gathered from Lego, with the goal of calculating the average sold price for those listings.
The issue I am encountering is that the scraper includes products listed under the "Results Matching Fewer Words" section, which are not relevant to my analysis. I have attempted to stop processing when the scraper encounters this selector, but doing so results in #N/A values being pulled instead.
Can you help edit this for use in python?
def fetch_ebay_average_price(ebay_search_url):
    """ Fetch the average sold price and count of sold listings from eBay sold listings page. """
    try:
        service = Service(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(ebay_search_url)
        time.sleep(3)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        price_elements = soup.select('span.s-item__price')

        prices = []
        for price_element in price_elements:
            try:
                price_text = price_element.text.strip()
                price_value = float(re.sub(r'[£,$,€]', '', price_text.split()[0].replace(',', '')))
                prices.append(price_value)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing price: {e}")
                continue

        driver.quit()
        if prices:
            average_price = round(statistics.mean(prices), 2)
            sold_count = len(prices)
            return f"£{average_price}", sold_count
        else:
            return "N/A", 0
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching eBay average price: {e}")
        return "N/A", 0

Here is an example product from lego and it's sold listings on ebay:
https://www.lego.com/en-gb/product/stable-of-dream-creatures-71459
https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=Lego%20Stable%20of%C2%A0Dream%C2%A0Creatures%2071459&rt=nc&LH_Sold=1&LH_Complete=1
When i inspect the ebay page, I focused on the following element:
srp-river-answer--REWRITE_START" element when inspecting the ebay page

GIve us a sample URL to look at.

@JeffC I have edited my post to include the URLs, thanks

It's probably best to select all items displayed in the search results list first. Then you can loop over the items, grab their prices, and stop when you encounter the separator "Results matching fewer words".
The following worked for me:
def list_ebay_search_results(url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless=new')

    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(url)
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

        items = soup.select('.srp-list li')
        for item in items:
            if 'srp-river-answer--REWRITE_START' in item.get('class', ''):
                notice = item.select_one('.section-notice__main')
                print(f'Found separator "{notice.text}". Stopping.')
                break
            name = item.select_one('.s-item__title')
            price = item.select_one('.s-item__price')
            if name and price:
                print(f'Found item "{name.text}" with price {price.text}')
    finally:
        driver.close()

It prints a bunch of product names and prices, and then stops:
...
Found item "LEGO Dreamzzz: Stable of Dream Creatures (71459) BRAND NEW FACTORY SEALED" with price £28.55
Found item "LEGO DREAMZZZ: Stable of Dream Creatures (71459) 681 Pcs. New In Box" with price £36.16
Found item "LEGO STICKER SHEET for 71459 Stable of Dream Creatures, NEW & Genuine!" with price £6.65
Found separator "Results matching fewer words". Stopping.

